# Swift unary operator error

Tags: swift

Why is it that when I have a line of code:

```
MoneyScreen1.text = "£" + String(moneyConstants.money) + ".00"
```

However on a different file of my project I have:

```
moneyLabel.text = "£" + String(moneyConstants.money) + ".00"
```

but I get two errors:

```
Consecutive statements on a line must seperated with a ';'
```

and

```
Unary operator '+' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'String'
```

but the line is almost exactly the same, other than a different name for the label being edited. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Full function:

```
func checkValues() {
    moneyLabel.text = "£" + String(moneyConstants.money) + ".00"
    let savedValues = UserDefaults.standard
    savedValues.setValue(moneyConstants.money, forKey: "money")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.jitterClickNumber, forKey:"jitterClickBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.macrosNumber , forKey:"macrosBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.autoClickerNumber , forKey:"autoClickerBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.anotherPCNumber, forKey:"anotherPCBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.workerNumber , forKey:"workerBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.houseNumber , forKey:"houseBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.officeNumber , forKey:"officeBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.skyriseNumber , forKey:"skyriseBuildingLevel")
    savedValues.setValue(buildingLevels.planetNuber , forKey:"planetBuildingLevel")
    jitterClickCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost) + ".00"
    macrosCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.macrosConstantCost) + ".00"
    autoClickerCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.autoClickerConstantCost) + ".00"
    anotherPCCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.anotherPCConstantCost) + ".00"
    workerCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.workerConstantCost) + ".00"
    houseCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.houseConstantCost) + ".00"
    officeCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.officeConstantCost) + ".00"
    skyriseCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.skyriseConstantCost) + ".00"
    planetCostLabel.text = "£" + String(buildingConstants.planetConstantCost) + ".00"
    moneyLabel.text = "£" + String(moneyConstants.money) + ".00"
}
```

Declaration of label:

```
@IBOutlet var moneyLabel: UILabel!
```

Comment: *"almost exactly the same"* does not help, we don't want to guess. Please post a *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Martin what do you mean? I am simply telling you that I don't understand why there is an error when the two lines that I am talking about are exactly the same, bar the variable name of the label?

Comment: I suspect the issue has to do with the _previous_ line (or other context). If you don't show the _actual code_, in its _actual context_, that causes the problem, we cannot help you. Remember, you do not know what we might need to know, so show enough information, including the surrounding context and the declaration of `moneyLabel`.

Comment: What I mean is some code which we can copy/paste into an Xcode project and reproduce the problem. See also: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @matt I've added the lines in

Comment: But it still isn't reproducible. I can't paste that code into a project and reproduce the problem, because it wouldn't come close to compiling. We would need the declaration of `moneyConstants` and `buildingLevels` too. Try it yourself. In other words, give us exactly what we need in order to get exactly the same error message. The way to work that out is to copy and paste code into a playground or iOS project until you get the same issue there. You will learn a lot by trying that. Maybe the issue is due to something from _before_ the `func` line! You'll soon know.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue is caused by the lack of a space after a plus-sign, in some way that you have failed to show us. I can summon exactly the same error messages with this code:

```
    func checkValues() {
        let s = "2" +String(100)
    }
```

Here's a screen shot showing the errors:

[image]

So my guess is that you are doing something like that.

Comment: I said it was a guess. You have not given enough information for us to reproduce the error. I, on the other hand, have shown code along with a screen shot that tells _exactly_ how to get the error. Now why don't _you_ do that — show _me_ how to get the error you are getting?